# Is there a way for JDK 11 to help me to strip unused code from a jar file?

Tags: optimization, java-11

Does JDK 11 include any way of either A) reducing the size of a application jar file by removing unreachable code, or B) producing some sort of report that identifies unreachable code?

I've been stuck on Java 1.8 until recently, and I've had the idea for a year or more that there was some sort of mechanism in JDK 11 like what I describe that I could make use of once I got my code to that version.  But now that I'm here, I'm Googling and looking through the JDK docs, and I can't find any such functionality.  Am I missing something?  I was so sure that there was a new linker, or something else that would do this for me.

Comment: If your code and its dependencies are modular then you can create a custom _runtime image_ using `jlink` that only contains the modules your application requires. But that doesn't remove code that is never used from individual modules.

Comment: Ah.  I think maybe that explains where I got the wrong idea.  I bet I heard about that way back when, but was now hoping it applied at a more granular level.  I'm not ready to modularize yet, and that probably wouldn't provide the level of granularity I'm looking for even if I did, so I'll have to get by with brute force analysis by eyeballs.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: There's _ProGuard_, but I've never used it and I'm not sure if it can be used with any Java application or just Android applications.